# Animating QGraphicsItem Efficiently

Tags: qt, animation, svg, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsSvgItem that I need to rotate a certain amount based on an external variable coming into my application. Currently I'm directly setting the rotation property of the item, but this appears to significantly drop my frame rate. (117.0 fps -> 98.0 fps) is this normal? Is this the correct way to animate a QGraphicsItem? I realize that the framerate sounds plenty high, but I'm concerned that as more items in the view are animated, that the performance will become a problem.

The code below is being called via a QTimer timeout signal at an interval of 0.

Note that I have also tried using a QGraphicsItem with a custom QPainterPath to draw the item rather than an SVG and it made no noticeable performance difference.

```
qreal diff = m_rope_length_ft[0] - m_rope_length_ft_prev[0];

qreal angle = diff * 5.0;

m_rope_reel[0]->setRotation(m_rope_reel[0]->rotation() + angle);
m_rope_reel[1]->setRotation(m_rope_reel[1]->rotation() + angle);

m_rope_reel[0]->update();
m_rope_reel[1]->update();
```

Answer (score 0):

A more proper way to animate in Qt is to use [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html). It requires that:

- your graphics item is inherited from both `QObject` and `QGraphicsSvgItem`;
- `rotation` is registered as property with [Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) (getters and setters already exist so there is no need to implement them).

Also you should try to tune graphics item's cache mode. [ItemCoordinateCache](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#CacheMode-enum) seems to be suitable for your case. There is also view cache mode, but it's hard to say which is better in your case.

Note that performance optimization should be done using average amount of items your program should be able to process. Optimizing a single item rendering may be pointless.